# System based on ESP32 goes off when placed with 380 V appliances

Tags: esp32, monitor, temperature

I have a problem with a circuit that I designed using esp32 and dht21 (temperature sensor) and some relays with sim800L and a DC-DC converter like the image

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yku5x.png)

This system monitors the temperature and the 230 V appliance and sends *short messages* ("SMS"s) when something is off.

The system works perfectly at home and for days without any bug (Watch dog is activated, and it auto restarts every 24 h) knowing that I have 230 V at home.

But when I place it in a garage that have 320 to 380 V appliances it goes Off, the temperature start going to -10 degrees celsius knowing that where I live it never gets that cold, and the system starts sending SMSs but the temperature is good (can be due to dht21 signal drop spike).

any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the answerable programming question here?